# Add and delete row in the table

Tags: javascript, html, row, delete-row

I am trying to write code for a table consisting of a textbox and a dropdownlist and a delete button on each row.

When the user click "Add Row" it adds another row that has the same elements on the first row. When user click "delete", it will delete that specific row as shown in the image here:

[add and delete row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sma9i.png)

Here is my code:

```
function deleteRow(r) {
            var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
            document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(i);
        }

       function myCreateFunction(n) {
            var tr = n.parentNode.parentNode.cloneNode(true);
            document.getElementById('myTable').appendChild(tr);
       }
```

The HTML:

```
<table id="myTable">
        <tr>
          <td >
          <input type="text" style="width:100%" />   
          </td>
      <td>
          <select>
                  <option value="Beginner" >Beginner</option>
                  <option value="Intermediate" >Intermediate</option>
                  <option value="Advanced" >Advanced</option>
              </select>
      </td>
          <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <input type="button" class="add" value=" Add Row " onclick="myCreateFunction(this)" />
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: There is **no** clear description in your question telling us what you perceive as error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are cloning not the `tr` but the parent of `add row` button, which is not a `tr`, but a parent with table in it. You just need to get first row of a table and clone it

```js
function deleteRow(r) {
  var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(i);
}

function myCreateFunction(n) {
  var tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].cloneNode(true);
  document.getElementById('myTable').appendChild(tr);
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" style="width:100%" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="Beginner">Beginner</option>
        <option value="Intermediate">Intermediate</option>
        <option value="Advanced">Advanced</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
  </tr>

</table>

<input type="button" class="add" value=" Add Row " onclick="myCreateFunction(this)" />
```